# converting timestamp to local time with PHP

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I'm trying to get a timestamp in local time with PHP from a mySQL database and I'm gettin errors, the original code that I was using was this, that obviously returned the UTC time:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['created']);
$dt = date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp);
```

Now searching in previous answers I've found this code:

```
$date = /* SELECT date FROM database */;
$usersTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver');
$l10nDate = new DateTime($date);
$l10nDate->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
echo $l10nDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But I couldn't make it work... I tried adding

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
```

too, but it dind't work neither... and I only did minimum changes because I want to save it in a variable not echo it.
Also, looking that information in that previous answer, I don't know neither if I can convert any UTC timestamp, or I have to insert the record in my timezone previously to can convert it back later.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `DateTime::construct` uses your local timezone. However your time is in UTC, so you need to tell the constructor that, and *then* modify the timezone:

```
$date = '2018-10-13 00:00:00';
$l10nDate = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$l10nDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver'));
echo $l10nDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output

```
2018-10-12 17:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! it worked perfectly. Another error that I was having was because I wanted to use the same line that I have been using to get the date from server to set the $date value. So using $date = strtotime($row['created']); was imposible to convert! Thank you again, for me that I don't speak so much english, the answer in addition to work was very clear.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad that I could help.