# How to convert DATE and TIME in MySQL to timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

This may be a weird question but how can I convert DATE and TIME into the supplied timezone "America/Chicago"?

For example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_date = $jobDate AND job_time = $jobTime");
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

`$jobDate` and `$jobTime` will be in UTC.

The selected output/results will be converted into the timezone "America/Chicago". How can I do that within the MySQL `SELECT` query? Thanks

(The code above does NOT take security into account, it's just an example)

Comment: get the data from the table and convert it according to the timezone

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
 $jobDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($jobDate));
And then pass to query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting timestamp to local time with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788664/converting-timestamp-to-local-time-with-php)